# SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'bmsswsxf_shahed'@'localhost' to database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel, laravel-8, cpanel-xmlapi

Hello i am facing Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'bmsswsxf_shahed'@'localhost' to database 'bmsswsxf_contentbasedapp' (SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = QLzDGJ8MYo3oBKG4WfD0PfQPkBkXJ7f0cZeuBz33 limit 1) problem when I try to run my project in cpanel

But I have update my .env file you can see this

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=bmsswsxf_contentbasedapp
DB_USERNAME=bmsswsxf_shahed
DB_PASSWORD=my pass is given here
```

Here is user name
[This is the image of user created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44v7W.jpg)

Comment: This sounds like it related to the operation you are trying to perform, and the permissions of that user to perform said operation.

Answer (score 0):

create a new user and password and save it in database it`s worked